# I can't set cookie

Tags: node.js, express

```
const express = require ("express");
const app = express();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());


app.use('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('HOME');
    const data = "John";
    res.cookie("token",data, {httpOnly:true});
    console.log(req.cookies.jwt)
})

app.listen(8000,()=>{
    console.log('server started...');
})
```

**I have also tried httpOnly:false but same error.**

*Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
at ServerResponse.header (D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
at ServerResponse.append (D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:732:15)
at ServerResponse.res.cookie (D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:857:8)
at D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\src\app.js:16:10
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
at ServerResponse.header (D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
at ServerResponse.append (D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:732:15)
at ServerResponse.res.cookie (D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:857:8)
at D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\src\app.js:16:10
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\DRIVE (E)\MERN\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)*

Answer (score 1):

`res.send()` sends the response from the server to the client, you cannot send another response. Sets your cookie headers before sending the response.

```js
res.cookie("token",data, {httpOnly:true});
res.send('HOME');
```

Perhaps you could read more on [cookie headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) and learn about the [http protocol on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP).